# What is the best graphing/charting toolset to use for creating Google Analytics type graphs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, google-analytics, graph, analytics

Given a Rails application on the server, what is the best charting/graphing solution for displaying dynamic, database driven charts/graph on a web page such as those available in Google Analytics.

An optimal solution would include components that can speak JSON back-and-forth with the Rails application via AJAX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While many good solutions presented above, the best imho is [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)

Including those suggested here, I rank the solution as follows:

1. [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)
2. [Open Flash Charts](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) (plugin: http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart)
3. [Ziya LiquidRails](http://ziya.liquidrail.com/) (which runs on top of [XML/SWF Charts](http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/))

The Google Visualization API is nice as well but not unless you're comfortable with everything running through their servers (which I doubt most are).  Insofar as my #1 option goes above, the only downside is cost (though there is a free lite version as well).

Thanks again for all the suggestions made above.

Answer (score 3):

Check [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/)

Comment: The google visualization API is slick and fits the bill EXCEPT that I cannot host the necessary javascript files locally.  There is no way my client is going to let requests be made to files hosted on google.  If I'm wrong that would be great as the library looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

how about open flash plugin ; 
i have created some nice graphs with this
http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart

Comment: open flash charts is intriguing.  other options i've found include:
* FusionCharts (http://www.fusioncharts.com/Default.asp)
* Ziya (http://ziya.liquidrail.com/)

Haven't committed to any one of these yet.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com).

Comment: nice solution but seems designed for ASP.NET

Comment: not at all. It's not related to ASP.NET in any way (except that there's a helper control for ASP.NET). There's also a third party wrapper class for RoR.

Comment: They released javascript crossbrowser version too: [link](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Morris.js is definitely worth a look.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised?view=asciicast
http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/